# Кто такие доезжачие?

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

В "Романсе генерала Черноты" А. Розенбаума есть такие слова:
*"Осенним утром псовая охота,

Борзые стелют, доезжачих крик...

Густой туман спустился на болота,

Где ждут своих тетерок глухари"*

А кто такие доезжачие и почему они, собственно, так называются?

Answer (score 1):

Доезжачий - это старший выжлятник на псовой охоте. По логике, "старший" должен быть один. Разве что запасного тоже прислали (мало ли, что на охоте случится). :)
По Далю "доезжать" - "доследовать зверя с гончими".